# How do I start a program at boot-time with a particular user after a few other services have started?

Tags: su, init-script, init.d, oracle-linux

I have an app that I'm looking to do the following with on Oracle Enterprise Linux 7:

- Run this app at bootup *after* certain other applications have started (one of them being MongoDB).
- I want to run this app with a particular user, because this user is customized with a particular set of permissions I need.
- This app needs to run on ports 80 and 443.  It is OK to customize the aforementioned user to allow it to use those ports without `sudo` (I just don't know how).
- The app's standard output and standard error streams should be redirected to a file.

How can I do this, ideally without reading seven manuals to do what I assume is a simple thing?

Answer (score 0):

Normaly, this is the job of init, upstart or systemd. Mostly there are already scripts for this job, like /etc/rc.local. And nearly every daemon comes with approbiated scripts for a safe start.

Quick 'n Dirty Solution: write a shell script to start the programm. It should solve the dependencices of user, permissions and other preconditions or simply wait some minutes. Enter the script with crontab -e as

```
@reboot sleep 120 && /full/path/to/script >& /var/log/mydaemon.log
```

Take a look at systemd-services!